# using std::span with void * and a length

Tags: c++, c++20

When interfacing with certain system API's, opaque buffers described by a `void *` pointer and a byte length are common. It would be advantageous to describe such buffers using a `std::span` of `std::byte`. While the below code example works in this regard, the function definition is complex and the function invocation is even more complex to the point of being less readable than passing `void *` and length pairs. And the quantity of such function definitions and invocations can be numerous. Is there a way to increase the readability of such function definitions and invocations, perhaps creating a hypothetical byte_view class or other techniques that allow both a `const` and non `const` opaque buffer to be described as seen in the below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <algorithm>
#include <span>


static void transfer(std::span<const std::byte> in_buf, std::span<std::byte> out_buf)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(in_buf.size(), out_buf.size()); ++i)
    out_buf[i] = in_buf[i];
}


int main()
{
  struct SYSTEM_PACKET
  {
    const void *in_buf;
    unsigned    in_len;
    void       *out_buf;
    unsigned    out_len;
    char        area[9];
  } packet { "abcde", 6, packet.area, 9 };

  transfer(std::span{ static_cast<const std::byte *>(packet.in_buf) , packet.in_len  },
           std::span{ static_cast<      std::byte *>(packet.out_buf), packet.out_len });

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why not a function with 2 overloads?  `byte_view(packet.in_buff, packet.in_len)`?  I might add a non-`void` non `sizeof(T)==1` `=delete` overload for safety.

Comment: "*perhaps creating a hypothetical byte_view class*" Why not a "byte_view" *function*? One that creates a `span` of bytes appropriate to the `void*` it is given.